# How can I specify the user inside my docker container?

Tags: docker

I don't want to be root inside a docker container.

I have tried the -u option but without success, if I call "id" inside the docker container I'm always root, what am I doing wrong?

```
docker run coursera -u 1000:1000 /grader/executeGrader.sh HgVw
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
```

Comment: is sudo su not an option?  Also maybe this will help: http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2015/12/don-run-as-root-inside-of-docker.html  last paragraph

Comment: sorry got the order wrong :(

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, got the order wrong:

```
docker run -u 1000:1000 coursera /grader/executeGrader.sh HgVwK
```